# Dynamic linq filter children using pivot

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I have business objects that look like the following:

```
class Project
{
    public int ID
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public string ProjectName
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public IList<ProjectTag> ProjectTags
    {
        get;set;
    }
}

class ProjectTag
{
    public int ID
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public int ProjectID
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public string Name 
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get;set;
    }
}
```

Example Data:

```
Project:
ID    ProjectName
1     MyProject

ProjectTags:
ID    ProjectID    Name     Value
1     1            Name 1   Value 1
2     1            Name 2   Value 2
3     1            Name 3   Value 3
```

Basically it's a way for our users to define their own columns on the Project. As a result, it's important to remember that I don't know the names of the ProjectTag entries at design time.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to give our users the ability to select projects based on search criteria using System.Linq.Dynamic. For instance, to select just the project in my example above, our users could enter this:

```
ProjectName == "MyProject"
```

The more complicated aspect is applying a filter to the ProjectTags. Our application currently allow users to do this in order to filter Projects by their ProjectTags:

```
ProjectTags.Any(Name == "Name 1" and Value == "Value 1")
```

That works, but starts to get a bit messy for end users to use. Ideally I'd like to write something that would let them do the following:

```
Name 1 == "Value 1"
```

Or if necessary (due to white space in the name), something like the following...

```
[Name 1] == "Value 1"
"Name 1" == "Value 1"
```

For lack of a better explanation, it seems like I want to do the equivalent of a SQL pivot on the ProjectTags, and then still be able to execute a where clause against that. I've looked at some of the questions on StackOverflow about pivots and dynamic pivoting, but I haven't found anything too useful.

I've also been thinking about looping through all the ProjectTag Names and building a dynamic query using a left join on each. I guess something like this:

```
select 
    Project.*, 
    Name1Table.Value [Name 1],
    Name2Table.Value [Name 2],
    Name3Table.Value [Name 3]
from
    Project
    left join ProjectTag Name1Table on Name = 'Name 1'
    left join ProjectTag Name2Table on Name = 'Name 2'
    left join ProjectTag Name3Table on Name = 'Name 3'
```

And then take that query and apply a where clause to it. But I'm not really sure how to do that in Linq as well as dealing with the white space in the name.

I also came across ExpandoObject. I thought possibly I could convert Project to an ExpandoObject. Then loop through all known ProjectTag names, adding each name to the ExpandoObject and, if that Project had a ProjectTag for that name, use that ProjectTag value as the value, else empty string. For example...

```
    private static object Expand(
        Project project,
        List<string> projectTagNames)
    {
        var expando = new ExpandoObject();
        var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>) expando;

        foreach (var property in project.GetType()
            .GetProperties())
        {
            dictionary.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(project));
        }

        foreach (var tagName in projectTagNames)
        {
            var tagValue = project.ProjectTags.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name.Equals(tagName));
            dictionary.Add(tagName, tagValue?.Value ?? "");
        }

        return expando;
    }
```

The exciting thing about this solution is I have an object that looks exactly like I think it should prior to filtering with a where clause. It even seems to accommodate spaces in the property name.

Then of course I found out that dynamic linq doesn't work nicely with ExpandoObject, and so it can't find the dynamic properties. I guess that's because it essentially has a type of Object which isn't going to define any of the dynamic properties. Maybe it's possible to generate a type at run time that matches? Even if that works, I don't think it can account for spaces in the Name.

Am I trying to accomplish too much with this functionality? Should I just tell the users to use syntax like ProjectTags.Any(Name == "Name1" and Value == "Value1")? Or is there some way to trick dynamic linq into understanding ExpandoObject? Seems like having a way to override the way dynamic linq resolves property names would be very handy.

Comment: I don't understand how the syntax that the user enters maps to C#. `ProjectTags.Any(Name == "Name1" and Value == "Value1")` isn't valid C#, so you must be doing some sort of parsing and translation there (although I'm not clear on what that is, or how `dynamic` comes into it). Since you're already doing that, can't you add logic to turn `Name1 == "Value1"` into `ProjectTags.Any(Name == "Name1" and Value == "Value1")`?

Comment: It's valid dynamic linq syntax. I do nothing but pass the user entered string into dynamic linq... projects.Where(customQueryStringTypedInByUser); In this case, "projects" is just an IList<Project>

Comment: Ah, you're using `System.Linq.Dynamic`, and you're doing `projects.Where("ProjectTags.Any(Name == \"Name1\" and Value == \"Value1\")")`? That wasn't clear.

Comment: I did a pivot earlier today with DataTables. See my code at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56097637/how-to-get-column-as-month-year-value-with-respective-values-of-column-in-sql-se/56098314#56098314

Comment: I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use System.Linq.Dynamic to filter a DataTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a translator to convert tag references?

I assume that tag names containing spaces will be surrounded by brackets (`[]`) and that `Project` field names are a known list.

```
public static class TagTranslator {
    public static string Replace(this string s, Regex re, string news) => re.Replace(s, news);
    public static string Surround(this string src, string beforeandafter) => $"{beforeandafter}{src}{beforeandafter}";
    public static string SurroundIfMissing(this string src, string beforeandafter) => (src.StartsWith(beforeandafter) && src.EndsWith(beforeandafter)) ? src : src.Surround(beforeandafter);

    public static string Translate(string q) {
        var projectFields = new[] { "ID", "ProjectName", "ProjectTags" }.ToHashSet();

        var opREStr = @"(?<op>==|!=|<>|<=|>=|<|>)";
        var revOps = new[] {
            new { Fwd = "==", Rev = "==" },
            new { Fwd = "!=", Rev = "!=" },
            new { Fwd = "<>", Rev = "<>" },
            new { Fwd = "<=", Rev = ">=" },
            new { Fwd = ">=", Rev = "<=" },
            new { Fwd = "<", Rev = ">" },
            new { Fwd = ">", Rev = "<" }
        }.ToDictionary(p => p.Fwd, p => p.Rev);

        var openRE = new Regex(@"^\[", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        var closeRE = new Regex(@"\]$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

        var termREStr = @"""[^""]+""|(?:\w|\.)+|\[[^]]+\]";
        var term1REStr = $"(?<term1>{termREStr})";
        var term2REStr = $"(?<term2>{termREStr})";
        var wsREStr = @"\s?";
        var exprRE = new Regex($"{term1REStr}{wsREStr}{opREStr}{wsREStr}{term2REStr}", RegexOptions.Compiled);

        var tq = exprRE.Replace(q, m => {
            var term1 = m.Groups["term1"].Captures[0].Value.Replace(openRE, "").Replace(closeRE, "");
            var term1q = term1.SurroundIfMissing("\"");
            var term2 = m.Groups["term2"].Captures[0].Value.Replace(openRE, "").Replace(closeRE, "");
            var term2q = term2.SurroundIfMissing("\"");
            var op = m.Groups["op"].Captures[0].Value;
            if (!projectFields.Contains(term1) && !term1.StartsWith("\"")) { // term1 is Name, term2 is Value
                return $"ProjectTags.Any(Name == {term1q} && Value {op} {term2})";
            }
            else if (!projectFields.Contains(term2) && !term2.StartsWith("\"")) { // term2 is Name, term1 is Value
                return $"ProjectTags.Any(Name == {term2q} && Value {revOps[op]} {term1})";
            }
            else
                return m.Value;
        });
        return tq;
    }
}
```

Now you just translate your query:

```
var q = "ProjectName == \"Project1\" && [Name 1] == \"Value 1\" && [Name 3] == \"Value 3\"";
var tq = TagTranslator.Translate(q);
```

Comment: I kind of suspected something like this might end up being the answer. Was hoping for something that was more out of the box, but this works well. Thanks for putting that together for me.

Comment: @Dan No problem, I have a kind of query translator in vbscript for some internal apps, and this will get me started on how to do one for C# when the internal apps are re-written (taking the concept of translating to Dynamic LINQ rather than to LINQ as an easier basis).